# NodeJS -> Mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

i have a problem with a query from NodeJS to MongoDb (i'm using native client).

Basically, i got 2 different results when performing the query from mongo console and from node app. (with native mongo client : i'm not using mongoose or other modules )

this is my query object (im using collection.find() ):

```
{ 'stats.campaign_id': 6010108824797,
  'stats.collectDate': { '$gte': 1375628400, '$lt': 1375632000 } }
```

Basically, the response from the Node app seems to be relative to only the first part of the query object ( campaign_id  ) : stats.collectDate isn't taken in account. (i get ALL the records relative to stats.campaign_id : result length > 100 )

From the mongo console, the query work as expected : results are filtered by stats.collectDate (results lenght = 3 ).

Do somebody know how to make the query works also from my node app, possibly without using different modules ?  And , what are the difference between mongoconsole and mongo node driver ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show the full code you're using in both cases?

Comment: Hi, the code is always the same : db.collection.find(queryObject) (the query object is the one in my question) , the problem is that results are different (it seems that query params are ignored from Node). I read somewhere that something change when executing commands from console or from node, but i didn't find anything explaining this.

Comment: its a bit late, for anyone trying to find answer for nodejs mongodb crud. please find  this tutorial. http://programmerblog.net/nodejs-mongodb-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

try warp your time stamps in Date Object in your node app

`{ 'stats.campaign_id': 6010108824797,
  'stats.collectDate': { '$gte': new Date(1375628400), '$lt': new Date(1375632000) } }`